# roslaunch gazebo_ros mars_world.launch cannot find mars.world

Tags: ros

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

I have a question regarding the directory structure expected by gazebo_ros when launching it using roslaunch.

I am using ROS Groovy, with Gazebo 1.9 and gazebo_ros_pkgs built from source.

I have a catkin workspace with `gazebo_ros`, where I have copied the following launch file (into `~/gazebo_src/catkin_ws/src/gazebo_ros_pkgs/gazebo_ros/launch`).

```
<launch>
  <!-- We resume the logic in empty_world.launch, changing only the name of the world to be launched -->
  <include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch">
    <arg name="world_name" value="mars.world"/> <!-- Note: the world_name is with respect to GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH environmental variable -->
    <arg name="paused" value="false"/>
    <arg name="use_sim_time" value="true"/>
    <arg name="gui" value="true"/>
    <arg name="debug" value="false"/>
  </include>
</launch>
```

I need to keep the mars.world in a separate folder (internal/project repository) - `~/faster_dev/branches/yn/gazebo/plugin` - which I have added to `GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH`. However when I try to launch gazebo with the command "`roslaunch gazebo_ros mars_world.launch`" I get the error that mars.world cannot be found.

I know that the mars.world works when I launch it with gazebo ("gazebo mars.world").

My environment variables are:

```
env | grep GAZEBO
GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH=:/home/yn/faster_dev/branches/yn/gazebo/models:
GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH=/home/yn/local/share/gazebo-1.9:/home/yn/local/share/gazebo_models:/home/yn/faster_dev/branches/yn/gazebo/plugin:/home/yn/faster_dev/branches/yn/gazebo/models
GAZEBO_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11345
GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH=/home/yn/local/lib/gazebo-1.9/plugins:/home/yn/faster_dev/branches/yn/gazebo/plugin/build:/home/yn/faster_dev/trunk/gazebo/plugin/build
GAZEBO_MODEL_DATABASE_URI=http://gazebosim.org/models
```

The relevant folders are

```
gazebo_ros: ~/gazebo_source/catkin_ws/src/gazebo_ros_pkgs/gazebo_ros
models: ~/faster_dev/branches/yn/gazebo/models (contains a databse.config and a number of models in subfolders)
world file: ~/faster_dev/branches/yn/gazebo/plugin
launch file: ~/gazebo_source/catkin_ws/src/gazebo_ros_pkgs/gazebo_ros/launch
```

Does anyone have any ideas why this could be giving me an error even though the world file path is correct (relative to `GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH`)?

I guess I could include "`~/faster_dev/branches/yn/gazebo/plugin`" in my global path, but I'd rather avoid this if possible..

Thanks!

Yasho

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/3910/roslaunch-gazebo_ros-mars_world.launch-cannot-find-mars.world/) by [ynevatia](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/448/ynevatia/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 41 on 2013-07-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I finally figured out the problem: it lies with the scripts in gazebo_ros/scripts. These call the setup.sh from Gazebo, which was overwriting the environment variables I had set in my .bashrc with default values.

By commenting out the relevant lines in *gazebo_ros/scripts/gazebo* and building it again (for safety), *roslaunch gazebo_ros mars_world.launch* works.

---

Originally posted by [ynevatia](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/448/ynevatia/) with karma: 41 on 2013-07-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0